# Typing indicator in Swift

Tags: swift, sockets, socket.io, swift2

I am using SocketIO in my Swift application, where the server emits, and the client listens. I want to display when a user starts typing, and was wondering how to accomplish this. I detect typing like this:

```
txtMessage.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)

func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
    //todo: how to let other clients know?            
}
```

Once I detect typing, how do I then let other clients know about it? Is it possible for the client itself to do a socket.emit, or do I need to send that to the server, and have the server do the emit?

I tried doing a socket.emit, the socket.on never gets the signal. When the server does the socket.emit, my socket.on listeners do receive the signal.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like the following: (This is in Javascript but the concept is here of how you would go about doing it)

**Client**

```
const input = document.querySelector('input')
const writing = document.querySelector('p')

input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  socket.emit('areTheyTyping', {
    typing: true
  })
  if (input.value.length === 0) {
    socket.emit('areTheyTyping', {
      typing: false
    })
  }
})

socket.on('areTheyTyping', function(data) {
  if (data.typing) {
    writing.innerHTML = 'User is writing'
  } else {
    writing.innerHTML = ''
  }
})
```

**Server**

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  const _id = socket.id
  socket.on('areTheyTyping', function(data) {
    if(data.typing) {
      io.emit('areTheyTyping', {typing: true})
    } else {
      io.emit('areTheyTyping', {typing: false})
    }
  })
})
```